# Admob test xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, admob

I am trying to implement and test admob ads for my application but nothing is appearing after the ad loading.

I implement it using xml :

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
          android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          customFont:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
          customFont:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

and i load it in when something is loading in my app :

```
    mAdView = (AdView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.adView);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.PutBoolean("_noRefresh", true);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(AdRequest.DeviceIdEmulator).AddTestDevice("my-device-id").AddNetworkExtrasBundle(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AdMobAdapter)), extras).Build();
    mAdView.LoadAd(adRequest);
```

I already use my Id and the test ID.
I used also different types of banners, but nothing change the ad not load.

Furthermore I have an error when the add try to load :

```
08-25 18:11:16.738 I/Ads     (12021): Starting ad request.
08-25 18:11:16.738 D/AppStreamingHelper(12021): Creating delegate
08-25 18:11:16.748 W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(12021): Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
08-25 18:11:16.748 D/GmsModuleFndr(12021): Staging file APK's and updating chimera config...
08-25 18:11:16.798 D/GmsModuleFndr(12021): Staging file APKs completed
08-25 18:11:16.798 W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(12021): Failed to load module version after staging: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
08-25 18:11:16.798 W/DynamiteModule(12021): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
08-25 18:11:16.798 I/DynamiteModule(12021): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
08-25 18:11:16.798 E/AppStreamingHelper(12021): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
08-25 18:11:16.888 I/Choreographer(12021): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-25 18:11:17.598 I/dalvikvm(12021): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
08-25 18:11:17.598 I/dalvikvm(12021): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
08-25 18:11:17.598 I/dalvikvm(12021): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
08-25 18:11:17.598 I/dalvikvm(12021): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
08-25 18:11:21.888 D/Mono    (12021): [0x6960bb60] worker finishing
Le thread 'Unknown' (0x4) s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
08-25 18:11:27.738 W/Ads     (12021): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-25 18:11:27.738 W/Ads     (12021): Failed to load ad: 0
```

I just want to work once to change the "display" of the ad.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

I add my manifest file if is can be useful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.askmethat.cheerup" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionName="1.0Beta" android:versionCode="4">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/CheerUpTheme" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState)]
```

Also make sure latest play services is installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads/29.0.0.2

for more information follow this tutorial link 
https://blog.tommyparnell.com/admob-with-xamarin-part-1-banner-ads/

Comment: In the manifest the permissions are added, i installed the google play serive ads too with nuget package managers & xamarin component but still the error. The only thing missing is the permission in the assemblyInfo.cs. I will do the change later in the day and come back to you. Thanks for the answer

Comment: the permissions in the assemblyInfo.cs don't change anything.

Comment: The same... and i already test C# implementation instead of XML implementation. Still the same error. I will edit my first post to add my manifest file

Comment: in your xml you customFont:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
          customFont:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"  what is customFont? I think that should be ads:adSize. Also try putting SMART_BANNER OR BANNER instead of MEDIUM_RECTANGLE

Comment: I change by ads like in google documentation and smart_banner but still the same error... i'm getting crazy

Comment: i'm also clueless. it should work. looks correct. can you try to use different banner_id ?

Comment: I already changed some times banner id creating new ad network, i also used the ids from google documentation, still the same error.

Comment: for know i change to Facebook ads and it work perferctly